# How to update seleniumjs types using @types/selenium-webdriver

Tags: javascript, typescript, selenium, selenium-webdriver, typescript-typings

The current selenium version we are using is 4.0.0-alpha-7 , how to know what version of @types/selenium-webdriver corresponds to this seelnium release . How seleniumjs release and typing release are mapped to each other

seleniumJS: https://www.npmjs.com/package/selenium-webdriver
selenium Typing: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/selenium-webdriver

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer from selenium maintainer community :

There is no one to one mapping between types and selenium version currently. Having types within selenium project is on road map and once implemented we don't have to use @types/selenium-webdriver.